# How Can I Echo Out 100% of the_post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, loops

So I query the posts, I get back everything that matches, then do my loop - but I want to do some sort of print_r type thing on each loop so I can see 100% of what data is being fetched. I've got a total brain block here.. Help!

Here is my query, and then my loop:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=property'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Just can't figure out how to echo out 100% of what was fetch through each iteration of the loop?

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to use the loop? If not then I would try:

```
<? $posts_array = get_posts('post_type=property');
print_r($posts_array); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your loop

`print_r($post);`

Answer (score 0):

I like to add the following to the top of any of my single php pages where I want to see the output...

```
<?php global $post; var_dump($post);die;?>
```

and in the loop :-

```
the_post();
global $post; 
print_r($post);
```